# image changes position on hover using float left

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, css-position

So I'm creating an image gallery with float left and everything is working great but then when i get to second row of images things go haywire. whenever i hover on image on the first row any image on second row position will get messed up by itself.

Here is the codepen. (my recent art looks way better than the one in codepen but you will get the idea whenever you hover over the image) 
try hovering over any image and see how second row image gets messed up..
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpGrVA

```
<html>
<body style="background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);">
<style>

.middlegallery{

   top:250px;
   position: absolute;
 }
 .mainpanel{
    left: 50%;
    right:50%;
    display:block;
    padding: 15px;
    /*top: 125px;*/
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 5px 3px 0 0;
   position: relative;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.gallery-image{
 margin:5px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 zoom: 1;
 float:left;
 cursor:pointer;
 position:relative;
 }
img:hover{
    border:1px solid #777;
}
img{

}
.middlewrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:95%;
    padding-top: 125px;
}



</style>
<div class="middlewrapper">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="mainpanel"><h5 style="font-family: Verdana, serif; text-align: left; position: relative; top: 3px;"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Recent arts</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="middlegallery">
  <div class="gallery-image">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You're using bootstrap, why not actually take advantage of one of the main reasons for using it, aka the layout grid, instead of doing this float stuff?

Comment: @ChrisW. can you give an example?

Comment: Sure, google "bootstrap grid tutorial" or "bootstrap image gallery" etc. There's loads of examples amigo. :)

Comment: @ChrisW. sure i will check it out thanks for telling me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `transparent` border for `img` and you solve it- your `hover` border is causing the problem

```
    img:hover{
        border:1px solid #777;
    }
    img{
      border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
```

A suggestion- add `display: block` or `vertical-align: top` to `img` to remove the whitespace characteristic of inline elements below the image.

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.middlegallery {
  top: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}
.mainpanel {
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  /*top: 125px;*/
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 5px 3px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.gallery-image {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  zoom: 1;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
img:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: block;
}
.middlewrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
  padding-top: 125px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body style="background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);">
  <div class="middlewrapper">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="mainpanel">
        <h5 style="font-family: Verdana, serif; text-align: left; position: relative; top: 3px;"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Recent arts</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middlegallery">

      <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x220">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much that's a great answer. it worked very nicely with display:block

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is when border gets added on hover the div gets bigger, and it pushes the other divs. Just add the border to the image.

```
img{
 border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: my bad i should of noticed that :/.

Answer (score 1):

Because on hover you add a border which means your element gets 2px larger and 2nd row positions it self according to longest element. Use shadow for this purpose

```
img:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #777;
}
```